# Solving problems regarding $L(x)=\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t},\quad x>0$ and the inverse function $E(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

#### The problem

Without using $L(x)=\ln(x)$ and given $$L(x)=\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t},\quad x>0$$

**a)** Prove that 
*i)* $L(xy)=L(x)+L(y),x,y>0$ 
*ii)* $L(1/x)=-L(x)$

**b)** Prove that $L(2)<1$

**c)** Prove that $L(3)>1$

**d)** Prove that $L$ is increasing

The number $e$ is $L(e)=1$ and $2<e<3$. 
Let $E$ be the inverse function to $L$, with $D_E=\Bbb{R}$ and $V_E=(0,\infty)$.
 Dont use $E(x)=e^x$.

**e)** Prove that $E$ is differentiable, and that $E'(x)=E(x)$

**f)** Prove that for all $x, y\in\Bbb{R} $ 
*i)* $E(x+y)=E(x)E(y)$ 
*ii)* $E(-x)=\frac{1}{E(x)}$

**g)** Let $n\in\Bbb{N}$. Prove that $E(x)^n=E(nx)$, and that $E(n)=e^n$

We can prove that $E(q)=e^q$ for $q\in\Bbb{Q}$. We define $e^x=E(x)$ for $x\in\Bbb{R}$, and consequently $L(x)=ln(x)$.

**h)** show that for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$ applies 
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=e^x$$

(Hint: Define the function $f$ like $f(t)=ln(1+xt)$ for $x\neq0$ and inspect $f'(0)$.)

#### My Work

**a)** *i)* $$L(xy)=\int_1^{xy}\frac{dt}{t}=\int_1^{x}\frac{dt}{t}+\int_x^{xy}\frac{dt}{t}=\int_1^{x}\frac{dt}{t}+\int_{\frac{1}{x}*x}^{\frac{1}{x}*{xy}}\frac{x*du}{x*u}=\int_1^{x}\frac{dt}{t}+\int_1^{y}\frac{du}{u}=L(x)+L(y)$$
Using $u=\frac{t}{x}$

*ii)*$$L(\frac{1}{x})=\int_1^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{dt}{t}=\int_\frac{1}{1}^{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{u}}\left(\frac{-1}{u^2}\right)du=\int_1^x\frac{-u}{u^2}du=-\int_1^x\frac{1}{u}du=-L(x)$$
using $u=1/t$

**b)** ?

**c)** ?

**d)** $$L'(x)=\left(\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t}\right)'=\frac{1}{x}$$ for all $x>0$ is $L'(x)>0$. $L$ is increasing.

**e)** $L:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ is continuous and strictly increasing, consequently the inverse function $E(x)$ is continuous and strictly increasing , and therefore differentiable?
$$E(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x e^t dt \quad??$$
and $$E'(x)=\left(\int_{-\infty}^x e^t dt\right)'=e^x$$
or is that using $E(x)=e^x$ and therefore not allowed?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Instead use the fact that the **derivative** of your function is $\frac{1}{x}$ which  is continuous and positive for all positive x.

Comment: You can compute Riemann sums for b) and c) to get the estimates.

Comment: I guess the *Mean-value inequality* should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

b)$$L(2)=\int_1^2\frac{dt}{t}$$
Note that for $t>1$, $0<\frac1t<1$. So if we imagine the average "height" of the function between $(1,2)$ is $0<h<1$ then the integral is equal to this height multiplied by the width, which is $1$. And so:
$$0<L(2)<1$$