# Prove that for all $x, y\in\Bbb{R} $ i) $E(x+y)=E(x)E(y)$ and _ii)_ $E(-x)=\frac{1}{E(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

#### The problem

Without using $L(x)=\ln(x)$ and $E(x)=e^x$ and given $$L(x)=\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t},\quad x>0$$

I have already proven that:
*i)* $L(xy)=L(x)+L(y),x,y>0$ 
*ii)* $L(1/x)=-L(x)$

that $L(2)<1$ , $L(3)>1$ and that $L$ is increasing.

The number $e$ is $L(e)=1$ and $2<e<3$. 
Let $E$ be the inverse function to $L$, with $D_E=\Bbb{R}$ and $V_E=(0,\infty)$.
 Dont use $E(x)=e^x$.

**1)** Prove that $E$ is differentiable, and that $E'(x)=E(x)$

**2)** Prove that for all $x, y\in\Bbb{R} $ 
*i)* $E(x+y)=E(x)E(y)$ 
*ii)* $E(-x)=\frac{1}{E(x)}$

**3)** Let $n\in\Bbb{N}$. Prove that $E(x)^n=E(nx)$, and that $E(n)=e^n$

#### My Work

**1)** $L$ is continues and strictly increasing and $L$ is differentiable for all $x>0$ , $x \in (0, \infty)$. Then $E$ is differentiable in $y=L(x)$ where $y$ is $y \in D_E=\Bbb{R}$ 
$$L'(E(x))*E'(x)=1$$
$$\left(\int_1^{E(x)} \frac{dt}{t}\right)' *E'(x)=1$$
$$\frac{1}{E(x)}*E'(x)=1$$
$$E'(x)=E(x)$$

**2** I see that what I need to prove now, is kind of the opposite of what I have alredy proven:
 *i)* $$L(xy)=\int_1^{xy}\frac{dt}{t}=\int_1^{x}\frac{dt}{t}+\int_x^{xy}\frac{dt}{t}=\int_1^{x}\frac{dt}{t}+\int_{\frac{1}{x}*x}^{\frac{1}{x}*{xy}}\frac{x*du}{x*u}=\int_1^{x}\frac{dt}{t}+\int_1^{y}\frac{du}{u}=L(x)+L(y)$$
Using $u=\frac{t}{x}$

*ii)*$$L(\frac{1}{x})=\int_1^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{dt}{t}=\int_\frac{1}{1}^{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{u}}\left(\frac{-1}{u^2}\right)du=\int_1^x\frac{-u}{u^2}du=-\int_1^x\frac{1}{u}du=-L(x)$$
using $u=1/t$

However I still don't know how to solve the problem, all and any help are welcome.

Comment: The OP asked this question as part of a larger question here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3123611/solving-problems-regarding-lx-int-1x-fracdtt-quad-x0-and-the-inverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $(i)$: we know for every $x>0,y>0$,$$L(xy) = L(x) +L(y)\quad (*)$$ For any $X,Y\in\mathbb R$, there is a unique $x,y>0$ such that $X=L(x), Y=L(y)$. Then applying $E$ to both sides of $(*)$ for these $x,y$, 
$$ xy = E(X+Y).$$
but $x = L^{-1}(X) = E(X) $ and $y = E(Y)$. Thus
$$ E(X)E(Y) = E(X+Y).$$

There's a similar game to play with $(ii)$, see if you can do it.

Comment: I managed to solve ii) thanks to you, but I still need help to solve numer 3. Do you have any more tips?

Comment: @qwert it follows from $(i)$, can you see it?

Comment: I see from (ii) that $E(-1x)=E(x)^-{1}$ ?? But I dont know how to prove that it is true for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: $(ii)$ involves $n<0$ but the question is about $n>0$ so $(ii)$ doesn't help. If $x=y$ in $(i)$, you get $E(x)^2 = E(2x)$, which is 3 with $n=2$. Can you see how to prove it for all other $n$?

Comment: I can show that it is true for $y=x$, and assume it works for $y=kx$ and then show that it is true for $y=(k+1)x$. And conclude that $E(x)^n=E(nx)$ is true for all $n \in \Bbb{N}

Comment: @qwert yup! good job